# how to create dataframe from json file if in row dataframe have more 1 data

Tags: python, json, row

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPtLK.png)
my json data like that, and i want convert to dataframe, and 'hastags' have more 1 data.

import pandas as pd
data1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['post id','sentimen','hastag'])

for i in range(0, len(dataku)):
currentItem=dataku[i]
data1.loc[i] = [dataku[i]['id'],dataku[i]['sentiment'],dataku[i]['hashtags']]
[image: output]

but i want output like this
[image: i want hastag one by one]

Comment: What does it mean that a json file has more than 1 file? Can you show a small sample from your json file? Also, you can format your code in the question so it will make more sense.

Comment: i mean, i have more than one data in a row of dataframe, and i want separate to one by one like the image

Comment: I'm guessing that each item in your json file contains multiple hashtags. If so, can you simply loop over each hashtag as you iterate over each item?